# WPF - ListBoxItem selection with LeftClick only

Tags: wpf, listbox, multi-select

I have a ListBox with SelectionMode="Multiple", which allows me to select multiple rows by clicking either the left or right mouse buttons. 
How can I restrict the selection to occur from the LEFT mouse button click only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you have to write your own ListBox(Item), override the

```
    protected override void OnPreviewMouseRightButtonDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPreviewMouseRightButtonDown(e);
    }
```

or

```
    protected override void OnMouseRightButtonDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseRightButtonDown(e);
    }
```

EventHandler and use your custom ListBox(Item) in your xaml. Don't forget to call e.Handled = true; you probably can also use one of the more general mouse event handlers and check if the right mouse button has been clicked and then call e.Handled.